# Replace ':43' in '8:25:43 PM' with RegEx

Tags: javascript, regex

I have to remove the seconds from `8:25:43 PM` by using the JS replace method.

I tried some different RegExs such as `/(:[0-9]{1,2})[^:]/g` but the problem is that it matches `:25` too. My goal is to remove `:43` only

Thank you very much.

Comment: replace anchoring not only with the `:` char, but with the `AM`/`PM` mark. Substitute `/:[0-5][0-9](\s+(AM|PM))/` with `"$1"`  (that `$1` will restore the `AM`/`PM` mark.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use negative look-ahead, like this:

```js
var result = '8:25:43 PM'.replace(/:\d+(?![\d:])/g, '');
console.log(result);
```

So, this removes a colon and digits after it, only when the next character after all that is not a colon, nor a digit.

If you could also have time indications in your input that are already without seconds, then you need to be more cautious, and first affirm that indeed you are removing seconds:

```js
var result = '8:25:43 PM'.replace(/(\d:\d+):\d+(?![:\d])/g, '$1');
console.log(result);
```

Comment: The regex in the second code snippet should probably be `/(\d+:\d+):\d+/g` to allow 2-digit hours.

Comment: That doesn't matter: the one captured digit will get reinserted after any digit that was already before it. It is not that `\d` prevents another digit from preceding it.

Comment: @HermanLauenstein Yeah, but that would include 3-digit hours :) Better to use `\d{1,2}`

Comment: Yes, but going that way you could also say that it would allow 30 as an hour part, so then you need to do `(1\d|2[0-3])`... etc. That is just going way too far for this question. The OP's problem was to identify the last digits, so I think this will do.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}):\d{1,2} (AM|PM)` with `$1 $2`.

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/reE2tx/1)

This captures the `HH:MM` and `AM/PM` parts and replaces the whole string with `HH:MM AM/PM`

```js
var result = '8:25:43 PM'.replace(/(\d{1,2}:\d{1,2}):\d{1,2} (AM|PM)/g, '$1 $2');
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

## Root cause

The `/(:[0-9]{1,2})[^:]/g` pattern matches the minute part in `8:25:43 PM` because of backtracking: after matching a colon, `[0-9]{1,2}` grabs `25` *greedily* and tries to match a char other than `:`. Since there is a `:` after `25`, the regex engine looks back and sees it can match one digit rather than two with `[0-9]{1,2}`, and it matches `2` with `[0-9]{1,2}` and `5` with `[^:]`.

## Solutions

Any of the already present solutions, or even a simpler one (given that there is always a space between the time value and `PM`/`AM`):

```js
console.log('8:25:43 PM'.replace(/:\d+(\s)/, '$1'));
```

## Explanation

- `:` - a colon
- `\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `(\s)` - a whitespace that is captured into Group 1 and is later restored after replacement is done with the `$1` backreference.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qOFXt2/1).